# Scroll view not scrolling with chart

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, achartengine

I was having some problem when trying to put a scroll view together with the chart in Android. For the chart, I am using achartengine plugin. Here is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewChartLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDisplayAttendeeAmt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/lightorange"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="people joined." />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_lightgrey_border" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDisplayPctMale"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="0 %"
        android:textColor="@color/lightblue"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Male" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDisplayPctFemale"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="0 %"
        android:textColor="@color/lightpink"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Female" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_lightgrey_border" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart_racesPie"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_lightgrey_border" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_lightgrey_border" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_lightgrey_border" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_lightgrey_border" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_lightgrey_border" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I got multiple charts to put inside one activity so I have to use a scroll view. However, the scroll view is not working. Any ideas?

If I removed  android:fillViewport="true" from scrollview and set its height to fill_parent, the charts is invisible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A ScrollView can only have one child.

Comment: I got one which is linear layout. I wrapped all my other components inside it

Comment: Your ScrollView is inside a layout?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean? This is the entire layout for that class. If I remove android:fillViewport="true" from scrollview, the chart is invisible

Comment: Sorry, I confused because the XML is on two parts. But, I see that you have more than one layout inside ScrollView. You have to put all inside a layout, because, if you put more than one layout, the ScrollView doesn't work.

Comment: I modified my question already. Yeah, I did but I wrapped it all with another linear layout just right under the scroll view.

Comment: Try with wrap_content instead fill_parent.

Comment: Can you be more specify? which layout with wrap_content height?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your current code. Just changed in `ScrollView`

**From :**

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

**To :** `

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

If contents exceeds the current screen size then you can scroll.

Thank you.